# Primes between gaps of size $nm - n$ for constant $m$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\; \exists\ m \in \mathbb{N}: \pi(mn) - \pi(n) > 0$, with $\pi(n)$ as the number or primes $ \le n$.

My hope would be that I can use the following which I just have proven: The sequence $ \pi(n_{i+1}) - \pi(n_i)$ is unbounded $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n_{i+1}/n_i \ge 1+\epsilon$, for a certain $\epsilon > 0$ and $\in \mathbb{R}$ (otherwise $\sum_i 1/p_i$ would converge). Can this work?

Comment: In fact, for all $n$ the inequality holds for $m = 2$.

Comment: Yes, I heared of that, its Bertrands conjecture then and was proven by Tschebyscheff, when I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Just use Euclid's theorem.

Comment: Dan, I think almost have it. So I try contradiction: If this ($\mathbf{A}$) would not hold, there would be always $n_i$ for which we have a zero prime gap ($\pi(n_im) - \pi(n_i) = 0$). It must be infinitely many $i$, otherwise one just would have to enlarge $m$ to cover the exceptions. As far as I see you have to show now that there then  even cannot be infinitely many non $n_i$ for which ($\mathbf{A}$) holds. But then it gets a bit difficult to get further.

Comment: Franky_GTH, that's essentially right, if this did not hold, there would be some $n$ for which we have a zero prime gap for all $m$.  Check the exceptional case $n=0$, and consider that the prime counting function and multiplication by a positive constant are both non-decreasing and unbounded functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The fact that $\sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}s$ diverges is sufficient to say that, for any sequence $n_i\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i}>1+\varepsilon$, the sequence
$$c_i=|S\cap[n_i,n_{i+1})|$$
is unbounded, where $|\cdot |$ is the size of a set. This is easy to prove since, were such a sequence bounded by some constant $k$, then we'd have that (assuming that $n_0=1$ without loss of generality):
$$\sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}s=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{s\in S\cap [n_i,n_{i+1})}\frac{1}s\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{s\in S\cap[n_i,n_{i+1})}\frac{1}{n_i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{n_i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(1+\varepsilon)^i}<\infty$$
which contradicts that $\sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}s$ diverges.

It's worth noting that the statement that $c_i$ is positive everywhere (which is closer to Betrand's postulate) has almost nothing to do with that sum diverging. For instance, a set like
$$S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n!,2n!]\cap \mathbb N$$
has that $\sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}s$ diverges, but for any sequence $n_i=k^n$ for fixed $k$, the asymptotic density of the $i$ such that $c_i$ is positive is $0$.

Comment: I see, so I am not correct (as I wrote I already had the proof for the unboundedness of $c_i$), since this then cannot be used to prove that $| S \cap [mn,n)| $ is never 0 for sufficiently large $m$?

Comment: @Franky_GTH Ah; it was unclear to me what "Can this work?" referred to in your question. In any case, no, the unboundedness of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes is not sufficient to prove that $|S\cap [mn,n)|$ is never zero.